# What happens to items if a player is attacked by two killers on the same night in online werewolv.es?

Tags: werewolv.es

In online werewolv.es, if two players holding a Potion of Acquiescence each simultaneously target item-holding Player X, the potion steals both 'bounce' and Player X gets to keep their item(s).

However if item-holding Player X is attacked the same night by two different killers, Player X will obviously die, but what happens to their item(s)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think @Shane's answer fully answers your question here.

I've just researched it with a test of a Wolf + Vampire both attacking a villager with items.

The current answer, which I think is unsatisfactory, is the kill that is resolved first will end up with the items (because double thefts bounce, but double kills don't).

I will mull over this situation this evening and think of a better resolution method. Whether that be bounce, or a predictable order of precedence for killers.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought Shane's answer meant the double kill 'theft' would also result in a bounce.

Comment: I realise I have mis-read that discord quote 100% of the times I have read it, and will delete my answer as it is obviously incorrect.

Comment: Maybe I/you should ask the question about item resolution order anyway, since it gets asked or referred to almost every item game anyway. That quote is still very useful.